# Trying to move text to the left but it's still aligned in the centre

Tags: html, css

I'm having some problems trying to keep my text to the left but keeps aligning in the center. I have to place the part I want to the left and entered in a div like some answers have told but it doesn't work. Here is my code if anyone would like to help me :)

CSS

```
.lord123 {
    text-align:center;
}

.lordbh {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-family: Khalifah;
    color: #FFD700;
    text-align: left;

}

.lordbp {

    font-family: arial;
    color: #FFD700;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}

.lordbpic {
    position: relative;
text-align:center;
display:block;
padding-top: 10px;

}
```

HTML

```
<div class="lordbpic">
<img src="/Users/Mushriff/Desktop/Website/Images/example.jpg" height="200" width="300">
</div>

<div class="lord123">

<h1 class="lordbh">Lord Bravo</h1>

<p class="lordbp">
INFORMATION
</p>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You could use `float: left;` and `text-align: center;` for `lord123`

Comment: Can you show what you are after? Maybe a mocked up screenshot or something. Your requirements sound contradictory.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this and adjust the `left: 40%;` so it fits your needs.

```css
.lord123 {
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
}

.centered-text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
}

.lordbh {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-family: Khalifah;
    color: #FFD700;
    text-align: left;
}

.lordbp {
    font-family: arial;
    color: #FFD700;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}

.lordbpic {
text-align:center;
display:block;
padding-top: 10px;

}
```

```html
 <div class="lordbpic">
   <img src="/Users/Mushriff/Desktop/Website/Images/example.jpg" height="200" width="300">
 </div>

 <div class="lord123">
    <div class="centered-text">
      <h1 class="lordbh">Lord Bravo</h1>
      <p class="lordbp">INFORMATION</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :**

```
.lord123 {

    width: 300px;// you can change width
    margin: 0 auto;

}
```

**Full code :**

```css
.lord123 {

    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.lordbh {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-family: Khalifah;
    color: #FFD700;
    text-align: left;

}

.lordbp {

    font-family: arial;
    color: #FFD700;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}

.lordbpic {
    position: relative;
text-align:center;
display:block;
padding-top: 10px;

}
```

```html
<div class="lordbpic">
<img src="http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/cute-bunny-1600x900.jpg" height="200" width="300">
</div>

<div class="lord123">

<h1 class="lordbh">Lord Bravo</h1>

<p class="lordbp">
INFORMATION
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple solutions to do this.

First of all, remove the `text-align: left` from `lordbh` and `lordbp`. This would overwrite the rule from `lord123`.

**Solution One**: You could add `float: left` and `text-align: center` to the class `lord123`.

See Snippet below:

```css
.lord123 {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.lordbh {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: Khalifah;
  color: #FFD700;
}

.lordbp {
  font-family: arial;
  color: #FFD700;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.lordbpic {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lordbpic">
  <img src="/Users/Mushriff/Desktop/Website/Images/example.jpg" height="200" width="300">
</div>

<div class="lord123">

  <h1 class="lordbh">Lord Bravo</h1>

  <p class="lordbp">
    INFORMATION
  </p>
</div>
```

**Solution Two**:
You could define a fixed `width` for the `lord123` and add `text-align: center`, this would place the div left automatically.

See Snippet below:

```css
.lord123 {
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}

.lordbh {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: Khalifah;
  color: #FFD700;
}

.lordbp {
  font-family: arial;
  color: #FFD700;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.lordbpic {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="lordbpic">
  <img src="/Users/Mushriff/Desktop/Website/Images/example.jpg" height="200" width="300">
</div>

<div class="lord123">

  <h1 class="lordbh">Lord Bravo</h1>

  <p class="lordbp">
    INFORMATION
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but I think you mean you want everything to be in a column that is as wide as the image, is that right?

The easiest way would be to just make all your elements 300px wide, but in case the image doesn't have a fixed width of 300px, you can use a CSS table.

```css
#everything {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.lord123 {
  display: table-row;
}

.lordbh {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: 'Khalifah';
  color: #FFD700;
  text-align: left;
}

.lordbp {
  font-family: 'Arial';
  color: #FFD700;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.lordbpic {
  display: table-row;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="everything">

  <div class="lordbpic">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" height="200" width="300">
  </div>

  <div class="lord123">
    <h1 class="lordbh">Lord Bravo</h1>
    <p class="lordbp">INFORMATION</p>
  </div>

</div>
```